# Checking if any instance of string in list

Tags: python

```
POarray = ['P.O. Box', 'P.O. BOX', 'P.O. box', 'p.o. box', 'PO Box', 'PO BOX', 'PO box', 'po box', 'P.O Box', 'P.O BOX', 'P.O box', 'p.o box']

if Resp_Info.r3.val in POarray:
     error('Sorry, but we cannot except PO boxes.')
```

I'm trying to raise an error if a PO Box is inserted into a value field.  However, PO boxes usually include numbers as well, like "PO Box 1167". How do I write my validation to check just for those instances in my string, and ignore the numbers.

Comment: Why not just remove any special characters and numbers from the string, convert to lowercase, and compare to `pobox`

Comment: Interesting, how would I do that exactly (not great in coding as you can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
if "pobox" in str(Resp_Info.r3.val).lower().replace(".", "").replace(" ", ""):
    print "err"
```

**Using Regex:**

```
import re
if "pobox" in re.sub('\W+','', "PO Box #1234" ).lower():
    print "err"
```

Comment: Your are Welcome :)

Comment: What about PO Box #1234?

Comment: @chrisz: can remove all special chars using regex. Solution updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('p\.?o\.?\sbox', re.IGNORECASE)

if re.search(pattern, Resp_Info.r3.val):
    error('Sorry, but we cannot except PO boxes.')
```